# Why my vuex store state chnage when i try to chnage the data using the method in my component?

Tags: vue.js, methods, vuex, state-management

I am making a small appliaction that allow the user to tell about their web application.

But In the Update component what I am doing is:

- When a component is created.
- Fetching the app from vue x store
- Setting the values in the data property
- And from data property taking it to the template

But the problem is when I try to update the stack of an app via methods `addTechToStack` by pushing the new value at the end of the app_stacks list it also changes the data of vuex state

**Here is the code**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="section">
      <div class="box">
        <h1 class="title is-4 has-text-centered">Update App</h1>
        <hr class="has-background-black" />
        <form method="POST" @submit.prevent="">
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label">App Name:</label>
            <div class="control">
              <input
                class="input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter App Name"
                v-model="updated.app_name"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label">App Subtitle:</label>
            <div class="control">
              <input
                class="input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter App Subtitle"
                v-model="updated.app_subtitle"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label">App Url:</label>
            <div class="control">
              <input
                class="input"
                type="text"
                placeholder="Enter App Url"
                v-model="updated.app_url"
              />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label">App Category:</label>
            <div class="control">
              <div class="select">
                <select v-model="updated.app_category">
                  <option value="" disabled>Select Category</option>
                  <option
                    v-for="(category, index) in categoreis"
                    :key="index"
                    :value="category"
                    >{{ category }}</option
                  >
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label">App Description:</label>
            <textarea
              class="textarea"
              placeholder="Description of your app"
              v-model="updated.app_description"
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <!-- IMP:Stack section  -->
          <div class="field">
            <label class="label">App Stacks:</label>
            <div class="field has-addons">
              <div class="control">
                <input
                  class="input"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Find Technology"
                  v-model="updated.stackTech"
                  id="stackTech"
                />
              </div>
              <div class="control">
                <button class="button is-info" @click="addTechToStack">
                  Add
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="box">
            <label class="label">Stacks:</label>

            <span
              class="tag is-medium mr-3"
              v-for="(tech, index) in updated.app_stacks"
              :key="index"
              >{{ tech }}
              <button
                class="delete is-small"
                @click="removeStack(index)"
              ></button>
            </span>
          </div>
          <!-- Stack section ends -->
          <div class="field is-grouped">
            <p class="control">
              <a class="button">
                Cancel
              </a>
            </p>
            <p class="control">
              <button
                type="submit"
                class="button is-primary"
                v-on:click="submitUpdate"
              >
                Update
              </button>
            </p>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "Update",
  data() {
    return {
      currentApp: null,
      categoreis: ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L"],
      //   Contains the updated value
      updated: {
        app_name: "",
        app_subtitle: "",
        app_description: "",
        app_url: "",
        app_category: "",
        app_stacks: "",
        stackTech: "",
      },
    };
  },

  methods: {
    removeStack(index) {
      console.log("Removed");
      this.updated.app_stacks.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(this.currentApp);
      console.log(this.updated.app_stacks);
    },
    addTechToStack() {
      this.updated.app_stacks.push(this.updated.stackTech);
      console.log(this.currentApp.stacks);
      console.log(this.updated.app_stacks);
    },
    submitUpdate() {
      // Check if user has updated any content
      if (
        this.currentApp.app_name == this.updated.app_name &&
        this.currentApp.subtitle == this.updated.app_subtitle &&
        this.currentApp.app_url == this.updated.app_url &&
        this.currentApp.category == this.updated.app_category &&
        this.currentApp.description == this.updated.app_description &&
        this.currentApp.stacks.toLocaleString()==this.updated.app_stacks.toLocaleString()
      ) {
        console.log("Cannot Update Beasue every vlaue is the same");
        console.log(this.currentApp.description);
        console.log(this.updated.app_description);
        console.log(this.currentApp.stacks);
        console.log(this.updated.app_stacks);
      } else {
        console.log("Updated");
        console.log(this.currentApp.description);
        console.log(this.updated.app_description);
      }
    },
  },
  created() {
    // const current = this.$store.state.your_apps[this.$route.params.index];
    this.currentApp = this.$store.state.your_apps[this.$route.params.index];
    this.updated.app_name = this.currentApp.app_name;
    this.updated.app_subtitle = this.currentApp.subtitle;
    this.updated.app_url = this.currentApp.app_url;
    this.updated.app_category = this.currentApp.category;
    this.updated.app_description = this.currentApp.description;
    this.updated.app_stacks = this.currentApp.stacks;
    console.log(this.currentApp);
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: If you don't want to mutate global state, then don't mutate it. In your case app_stacks is the object from global state. Clone it, or else.

Comment: I'm not seeing where you're actually using a vuex store, this is usually done in computed getter/setters. Your problem often occurs when you're mutating a property you're getting from your store (like Array.push() in this case). Instead, replace the existing array with a new one containing the added entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're assigning a reference the same object (array) to a different variable.

So `this.updated.app_stacks === this.currentApp.stacks` are both references to the same array. So if you mutate one, you mutate the other.

To avoid this, you'll have to create a copy of this array in order to create a new reference and detach both array.

If you array is hosting primitive values (i.e. not arrays or objects), you can make a shallow copy. There are a lot of ways to do so, here is one:

```js
  this.updated.app_stacks = [...this.currentApp.stacks];
```

> **Side note**: in your `data()` initialisation, `this.updated.app_stacks` should be an empty array, not an empty string. It doesn't change anything since you overwrite it in `created`, but it's kind of confusing when reading the code.